# Solution of simultaneous equations to get desired value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Let $a,b,c,d \in R$ and

$$a \sec (200 ^\circ)-c \tan(200 ^\circ)=d$$

$$b \sec(200 ^\circ)+d \tan (200 ^\circ)=c$$

If $\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{ac-bd}=\lambda \csc(200 ^ \circ)$, then find the value of $\lambda$.

I found values of $\sec(200 ^\circ)$ and $\tan(200 ^\circ)$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$ which are $\sec(200 ^\circ)=\dfrac{c^2+d^2}{ad+bc}$ and $\tan(200 ^\circ)=\dfrac{ac-bd}{ad+bc}$ and which ultimately yielded $\csc(200 ^\circ)=\dfrac{c^2+d^2}{ac-bd}$ but I cannot proceed further. How should I bring $a^2+b^2$ into picture and ultimately find $\lambda$.

Comment: Were you able to get the answer with my hint?

Comment: @ACB Yes. I got answer as 2. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the two equations by $\cos x$, ($x=200^\circ$ here), to get,
$$d\cos x+c\sin x=a$$ $$c\cos x-d\sin x=b$$

Square and add. You may see the answer.